# How to keep my style theme in NP++?

Tags: notepad++

I have been using Notepad++ for a while and I really like the Monokai theme with some custom tweaks to the fonts. But for some reason every time I close NP++ and shut down my computer; the next time I open up my NP++ it has reverted to the original theme. It gets kind of old having to reset my preferred styles every time I come to work.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you list the steps you take to change the styles and save the changes?

Comment: I do Setting->Style Configurator->Select Theme: Monokai-> A few CSS and HTML font color configs-> Save & Close. The reset only happens after a full shutdown and restart. It doesn't happen when I just close and re-open NP++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried saving the changes directly in the NotePad++ config files?
I had the same problem with it not saving my custom file extensions. Every time I rebooted, the custom extensions in "Style Configurator" disappeared. After I added them to the styles.xml file, they became defaults.

In your case you have to edit the relevant portion of the stylers.xml file, changing the color value of the color you want to change.

Test that. If after the reboot the file was reset, then I think your operating system is restoring the files to the original state at every boot (wich just seems weird), but I've seen it before :/

Comment: Actually, langs.xml was the file that did it ;)

Answer (score 63):

It happens because you are not running the program as administrator. On Windows 7, right click on the shortcut and select "Run as administrator". Make the changes to the styles, save them as usual and close the program. The changes will be there on the next start.

Comment: This solution fixed my problem, and seems a lot simpler!

Comment: For the record, in my case this didn't work (Notepad++ v6.7.8.2, Win8x64). Making the changes as administrator and then opening Notepad with a standard user did not keep the changes. Opening Notepad with the administrator again, however, did keep the changes. (It's worth mentioning the administrator account in my case is different from the standard user, so perhaps the changes are saved for the administrator account and that explains it). I was forced to apply the changes to the files manually.

Answer (score 10):

**This is a simple problem. Folder write permition is needed for save configs.**

> Change c:\program files(x86)\notepad++ permition
>
> or
>
> Run Notepad++ as Administrator

Comment: This worked for me. I ran as Administrator and the settings saved, and they're still there when runnign normally. Changing the permisisons of the folder had no effect, but maybe I was changing the wrong folder/wrong permission (Windows permissions are mystifying to me).

Answer (score 9):

I've faced the same problem.

What I figured out: **run notepad++ as administrator** and it will keep the changes. After that you can run as regular user (the changes made will be reloaded).

I think this might be a file permissions issue. Those configurations are saved as .xml files, that only administrators have permissions to modify.

Answer (score 3):

Okay after 35mins of fiddlin', You actually have to apply the global effects, then

1. Select HTML or CSS or (whatever you're working on)
2. Edit the HTML or CSS , then
3. BEFORE saving, look to the left and ADD your "USER ext.:"

save.

Note* To save as you're original theme, Go to where the THEMES are saved, and copy paste a 2nd copy, to edit second copy, follow steps above! Share the Wealth!![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly convinced the problem I'm having with this is a feature/bug in Notepad++ regarding saving settings when you run it using different credentials, depending on exactly the circumstances. Just running as "Admin" may be a work-around, but it intentionally circumvents security, and it also gets rid of the ability, for instance, to have different colors as an indication of which permissions you're running the app under in the first place.

Unlike most days, on which I'm popping back and forth between using Notepad++ as a normal user (clicking its icon, or executing it from a `cmd.exe` shortcut executed as a normal user), and running it as an Administrator (clicking a shortcut I created with the "Run As Administrator" option ticked, or from a `cmd.exe` shortcut created similarly), today I was using a special-purpose Visual Studio Command Prompt I created that runs under separate credentials as the *local* admin. And POOF all my settings were gone.

I have tried various things, none of which seems to help much, but this seems (so far) to be helping me: in the `Settings > Style Configurator` window, in addition to all the color settings, there's a dropdown labeled "Select theme:". After playing around with it a bit I finally noticed that the theme had been changed to the default, whereas I had been using one of the dark themes. So, I popped back over to it and (yay!!!) my settings still seemed to be saved under that.

Now, to be fair, the way UAC works, when you are running "as Administrator", your credentials will still show up as `DOMAIN_OR_PC_NAME\USER_NAME` (e.g., `whoami` at a command prompt), and your environment, I believe, still shows the same. So, in this case, I see arguments for Notepad++ either behaving as it does (by using your personal AppData directory).

However—*and this is why I believe it **may** be a bug, although I haven't yet done enough troubleshooting to be 100% confident in saying it is, so I won't*—today, I was actually running under a `cmd.exe` shortcut that is run under the local admin account directly. Indeed, I was just able to verify the behavior by <kbd>shift</kbd> clicking a `cmd.exe` shortcut, choosing `Run as a different user`, and logging in as the local admin. Now, `whoami` shows "MY_COMPUTER_NAME\LOCAL_ADMIN_USER_NAME", and %USERPROFILE% shows as "C:\USERS\LOCAL_ADMIN_USER_NAME", but, still, when I load up Notepad++, it seems to be pulling settings from/pushing them to, my user account.

So, here's what I am going to do until I can get things nailed down, and hopefully fixed: 1. put the Notepad++ `AppData` directory back under revision control, so if it gets hosed, I can just revert changes. (I may also try making it read-only.) 2. In `Settings > Preferences` on the `Multi-Instance` page, under `Multi-instance settings` I have selected `Always in multi-instance mode`. I have verified that, when I select this mode, my original Notepad++ will stay up, with the original settings, even if I open from another user. This way, I have the opportunity, if I was running under a different account first, to (a) exit out of the one loaded by the account with the wrong settings, (b) make a trivial change in the style configurator, and (c) save the settings again. And, 3. I am going to select a different theme in the configurator while loading Notepad++ in each different account, so that hopefully the changes I make to each will stick, and the most I'll ever have to do is change that one dropdown to fix things.

There are still some issues, for instance, when I did this, the first three times I opened Notepad++ under the local admin account, it opened up three entirely different sets of files or, more accurately, no set of files the first time, and then two different sets, I'm not sure where it got them from, as it seems to differ from the one that comes up running from user or normal `Run as administrator` mode; but I didn't look carefully enough to see since I wasn't expecting this behavior. Once I have a chance to do more troubleshooting, and assuming I can figure out a good way to repro all the problems, I intend to file a ticket in the Notepad++ bug tracker; it's an awesome product, and from the bug reports I've read they seem more than willing to try to troubleshoot things when there are real issues.

Comment: It's a pain. It was as if N++ had performed a silent setup on boot and replaced all the themes in Roaming with default ones. From where? Who knows? An older set of themes was in the N++ application directory- so it wasn't them. So the plan now is to run N++ as admin at every invocation. Doing that and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/212914/shellexecute-failed-2-error-for-notepad-on-windows-7-64bit) happens. And so it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and don't see the solution I applied here, which worked. For some reason, the `Start In` box on the properties of the Notepad++.exe pointed to an `AppData\Temp\2\nppLocalization` folder, but this was within the profile of a different user account, not mine. Also this folder didn't exist.

So I cleared the `Start In` box, and this corrected the issue for me.

- Right Click the `NotePad++.exe` file in explorer
- Select the `Shortcut` tab
- Clear the `Start In` box.
- Restart Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this ANNOYING behavior of N++ for a long time.

At the end what helped me to set it up right away (not fix the bug) was just overriding the setting manually.

**All you have to do is** to replace the content of the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\user.manual\Notepad++\stylers.xml` with the xml code of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\themes\Black board.xml` or the XML of the style you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when logged in as a standard user on Windows 7 Pro. As a standard user no themes were available. If I ran as an Administrator or logged in as one, the themes were available and would save changes. I found that under my Standard User account there was no "themes" folder in the AppData directory for my account (C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++). I logged into my Administrator account and found that the themes folder was there. I copied it from my Admin AppData directory to my Standard User one. Themes are now available and the settings save.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy XML files from location:
c:\Users\USER_NAME\appdata\Roaming\Notepad++\

It works in my case. Notepad saves there all styles changes and configurations.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have admin privileges to the installed folder, to get this to work I manually edited the "langs.xml" file located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++  directory....this needs to be opened and edited. Manually add the extension in the xml. Save, reopen NP++...voila.

I wanted inc, int, mdl associated with C++ language styles...

Change this …
        Language name="cpp" ext="h hpp hxx cpp cxx cc" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/"

…to this… (with your extensions)

```
    Language name="cpp" ext="h hpp hxx cpp cxx cc int inc mdl" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/"
```

The extensions should show-up in your "default ext." list now in the  style configurator for the language you want associated with extensions.

Hope that helps!